# Rename a tab title in an ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Ionic and vscode so I started a new project of ionic in vscode. For testing purposes, I renamed HomePage to AccountPage - all references were changed as expected. I also renamed Home folder + 3 files (ts/html/css) to account and their references in the code.

I then changed Home to Account in account.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Account</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

and in tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Account" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Contact" tabIcon="contacts"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

The only error I see is in account.ts under `@Component({`

```
[Angular] Component 'AccountPage' is not included in a module and will not be available inside a template. Consider adding it to a NgModule declaration
```

and I'm not sure what to do with it because there are no more Home references anywhere in the code. Also, when running the app, it works with no error except for the fact that I still see Home in the app (browser) instead of Account. What am I missing?

account.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-account',
  templateUrl: 'account.html'
})
export class AccountPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { AccountPage } from '../pages/account/account';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    AccountPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    AccountPage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Can you include the ts part of the accountspage? also does it have accounts.module.ts?

Comment: Added. I don't see account.module.ts. There was also no home.module.ts

Comment: In that case what is declared in app.module.ts?

Comment: import { AccountPage } from '../pages/account/account'; . other HomePage references in this file were changed automatically to AccountPage

Comment: I wonder why I don't get any error when running the app. Maybe it uses the "previously compiled" version from "before" the error (just a guess).

Comment: Can you add app module code to the question?

Comment: Added. I simply wanted to change the title of a page, I didn't know it would be so complicated :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also changed the tabs.ts file, right? I dont see any error here. 
Maybe you forgot to save every file you changed then execute ionic serve?

Comment: after deleting the www folder and running ionic serve, I do see Account as expected but the error in account.ts under @component is still there. Is that mean I will need to do it for any change?

Comment: I had to close and re-open vscode for the errors to go away even though I made the changes from inside vscode. The same happened when I changed About to something else. Shouldn't it handle this better? Am I missing something?

Comment: You dont need to delete www folder. Can you enumerate the steps you did when the error occured?

Comment: The errors are errors that were already fixed, but the red zigzag disappears only after closing and re-opening the file. Another user complained about it in github.